# Function call hangs

Tags: node.js, camunda

I have the following code in my index.js file. This was my attempt to implement an external task worker for Camunda in node js after cloning this [repo](https://github.com/nikku/camunda-worker-node).

```
var Workers = require('camunda-worker-node');
var Backoff = require('camunda-worker-node/lib/backoff');

try {
    console.log('In try  ');
    console.log(Backoff)

    var engineEndPoint = process.env.ENGINE_URL || 'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest';
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}

console.log("Out of try");

var uuid = require('uuid');
var workers = new Workers(engineEndPoint);

try {
    Backoff(workers);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

workers.subscribe('FightTribe', ['name'], function (context, callback) {

    console.log("in worker subscribe");

    if (Math.random() > 0.9) {
        console.log('German Tribe Fighter, The Battle is lost.');
        return callback(null, {
            variables: {
                legionStatus: "defeated"
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('German Tribe Fighter, The Battle is WON.');

    callback(null, {
        variables: {
            legionStatus: 'Victorious'
        }
    })
});
```

My camunda process engine is up and running. On starting up *index.js* the process hangs at the function call `Backoff(workers)`.

In an attempt to debug i placed  `console.log("in worker subscribe")` in `workers.subscribe`, but the execution never reaches there.

I have attached my working directory. I am not sure what the issue is.

[image]